# JS DOM order issue

Tags: javascript, html

I ran into a weird issue I can't seem to figure out.
I have this basic JS code

```
var myList = document.getElementById("my-list")
myList.innerHTML += "<li>3</li>"

document.body.innerHTML += "<p id='paragraph'>V School rocks!</p>"
document.getElementById("paragraph").style.textAlign = "center"



var a = document.createElement("li")

a.textContent = "element"
console.log(myList)
myList.append(a)
```

and this html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="my-list">
            <li>0</li>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
        </ul>

        <script src="demo2.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
    </body>
</html>
```

the last line of JS code does not append my element into the list although if I console log the list it shows the element as existing there.

In order to make this code work properly, I have make one of the following updates:

1. remove the 4th and 5th lines of code.
2. redeclare the myList variable below the 4th and 5th lines of code.

Any idea why this happens?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your html seems to be invalid. there should be exactly two HTML two HEAD and two BODY tags(opening and closing) : <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="my-list">
            <li>0</li>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
        </ul>
        <script src="demo2.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `document.body.innerHTML +=` breaks the reference of variable `myList` as `+=` gets the HTML from the DOM and reinserted entire HTML again.

*Note: Use [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)* not `.append`,  ***The `Node.appendChild()` method adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node.***

A simple hack would be to redefine the variable "myList" as initially declared variable has lost the reference(Not recommended).

```js
var myList = document.getElementById("my-list");
myList.innerHTML += "<li>3</li>"
document.body.innerHTML += "<p id='paragraph'>V School rocks!</p>";
document.getElementById("paragraph").style.textAlign = "center";

myList = document.getElementById("my-list");//this line will access the element again.
var a = document.createElement("li")
a.textContent = "element"
myList.appendChild(a)
```

```html
<ul id="my-list">
  <li>0</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

I would not recommend `innerHTML +=` approach, use `Element.appendChild` where you can use an earlier defined variable and it does not disturb the entire DOM tree.

```js
var myList = document.getElementById("my-list");
var liElem = document.createElement('li');
liElem.textContent = "3";
myList.appendChild(liElem);
var pElem = document.createElement('p');
pElem.id = "paragraph";
pElem.textContent = "V School rocks!";
document.body.appendChild(pElem);
document.getElementById("paragraph").style.textAlign = "center";
var a = document.createElement("li")
a.textContent = "element"
myList.appendChild(a)
```

```html
<ul id="my-list">
  <li>0</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: document.body.innerHTML += breaks the reference? really?? Is it true only for body, or for any tag? Didn't know that

Comment: @НадильКаримов - `innerHTML` is equivalent to _get entire HTML, update it and reinsert it again_

Comment: @НадильКаримов Thanks a lot for your reply. I understand :). What I wierd tho, is that if I console.log the myList variable after the innerHTML it still has it's content even if I don't reassign it.

Comment: @AlexD - Because things are still in the memory!